# Unable to handle texbox using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working in Reactjs and using Nextjs,I am facing problem with "text box",whenever i use "value" in textbox then i cant type anything in "textbox" and if i use "defaultvalue" in "textbox" then i am getting validation message "Please enter your email"
How can i fix this ?
Here is my code

```
<input
 type="text"
 name="email"
 id="email"
 placeholder="Type your email here"
 value={state.name}
 onChange={handleChange2}
 />
```

And here if nextjs code

```
const value = e.target.value;
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.email]: value
    });
  };
  const handleSubscribe = (e) => {
  
  
e.preventDefault();

//if (state.email == '') {
if (value.email == '') {
  $("#error2").show("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut();
  $("#msg2").hide();
} else {
  $("#msg2").show("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut();
  $("#error2").hide();
  //alert(state.email);

  const data = {
    name: value.email
  };                        // making array and will pass to api as parameter
  //input type text empty after click
  setState({
    ...value.email,
    name: ""
  });

  axios.post('https://diggdevelopment.com/blackstallion_new/api/testinfo/', data).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
}
```

};

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to use API(subscribe after user enter his email)

Comment: looks like value should be value={state.email}

Comment: @Azzy: not working

Comment: please add your `handleChange2` function code

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-glitter-ed0t7z?file=/src/App.js:58-409 ?

Comment: in seetState  chane [e.target.email]: value to [e.target.name]: value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState({});

const handleOnChange = (event) => {
  setValue({...value, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
}

const handleSubscribe = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (value.email === '') {
    $("#error2").show("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut();
    $("#msg2").hide();
  } else {
    $("#msg2").show("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut();
    $("#error2").hide();

    const data = {
      email: value.email
    };
    setState({
      email: ""
    });
    axios.post('https://diggdevelopment.com/blackstallion_new/api/testinfo/', data).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
};

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubscribe}>
    <input
      name="email"
      value={value.email}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
    />
      <button>Send</button>
    </form>
);
```

Comment: but i am using form submit like this 

<form onSubmit={handleSubscribe}>

so should i remove this ?

Comment: No. That's ok. I updated the code.

Comment: How can i get this input value inside "handleSubscribe " function ?

Comment: Actually i am very close to fix this , i want to post this email in axios but right now unable to post, i just updated my question , right now i want to clear input type text after click on button and pass email to axios api, Kindly tell me how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This could work, minimal example to reproduce

```
input prop
name => name="email"
// set state with [e.target.name]
setValue({ ...value, [e.target.name]: e.target.value  })
```

---

```
   const YourForm = (props) => {
  
      // value variable will contain the latest value of the input
      const [state, setState] = React.useState({})

      const [isPosting, setIsPosting] = useState(false)

       const postApiCall = async = (data) => {
         try {
            setIsPosting(true)
            const response = await axios.post("postUrl", data)
            // can handle success message here too
            setIsPosting(false)
         } catch(error) {
              setIsPosting(false)
         }
       }

    const handleSubscribe = async (e) => {
             e.preventDefault();
             const email = value?.email;
             // validate and submit
             const postData = { email }
            
             const response await postApiCall(email)
             // better to clear fields after success
             setValue({ email: '') // clear email  
             //if (response.isSuccess) {
             // show some toast/message
             //}
    }

    
      return (
         <form onSubmit={handleSubscribe}>
          <input
           name="email"
            value={state.email}
            onChange={(e) =>setValue({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value  })}
             />
           // disable button when isPosting flag is true
           <button   />
       </form>
      );
```

Basic explanation of event handlers

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => {
    
   // will be created for every render, but looks cleaner
   // this can be wrapped with useCallback if needed for optimization
   const onTextChange = (event) => {
     // event handling code
   }

   return (
     ... other render code
     <input onChange={onTextChange} />
     ...
     <input onChange={(event) => {  
       // in line event handler
       // will be re created for every render
     }} />

   )


}
```

React new documenation on [event handling](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/responding-to-events) will give you idea of standard practices

Hope it helps

Comment: but i am using form submit like this 

<form onSubmit={handleSubscribe}>

so should i remove this ?

Comment: means ? Please explain

Comment: How can i get this input value inside "handleSubscribe " function ?

Comment: I edited the answer, but you where doing the right thing in the question

Comment: Actually i am very close to fix this , i want to post this email in axios but right now unable to post, i just updated my question , right now i want to clear input type text after click on button and pass email to axios api, Kindly tell me how can i do this ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for